# CSS..I cant reflow site with css like chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I am not good at responsive stuff, i designed my site for high resulation , so when i try to use it low resulation its looks bad, i fixed it for google chrome with:

```
 body {
     zoom: 80%;           
 }
```

But still looks bad for ie and mozilla , i try "transform" and "scale" stuff but they didnt work out, they zoom out like you zooming picture, they didnt reflow pages.. I need something that works like browser zoom property.

Thank You

Comment: i don't think it has anything to do with the size of your monitor. Resolution of your screen matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways to accommodate Mobile/Tablet devices with your website.

**FIXED DESIGN**

Create a stylesheet that works generically across all formats. Your site will appear the same on all devices but this process will be the simplest solution.

The fixed design process should primarily use percentages and max-widths to create content that changes based on the device width.

*PROS*

When used well this process uses least resources and is faster to create and modify.

*CONS*

If your site has large amounts of content on a page then your site can become very cramped on smaller devices

**RESPONSIVE DESIGN**

If you want your site to be viewed differently and arguably optimally on different devices then you need a responsive design. This can be achieve by using a dynamic stylesheet or by using multiple stylesheets for different devices.

*PROS*

A very versatile website that can be display uniquely and optimally based on the viewing device.

*CONS*

Larger or additional resources and marginally longer loading depending on design. Longer development and modification times.

---

**CREATING RESPONSIVE CASCADING STYLESHEETS**

It is no longer practical to use set width becuase there are simple to many varible sizes.
The answer is flexible everything.

- Using a viewport metatag as in your example to target the device
  that is accessing your website.

  `<meta name="viewport"
  content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0,maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no"/>`

  There is clearly demand for the viewport meta tag, since it is supported by most popular mobile browsers and used by thousands of web sites.
- Using media queries.

Media Queries let you write individual rules for specific screen widths.

```
/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (max-width : 320px) {
/* Styles */
}
```

- Using Javascript.

A good javascript solution other than bootstrap is **[jquery mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/)** which takes away the time and effort of designing a responsive site by doing the work for you.
You do not need to know or edit any javascript to use it.